# Android M Permission list not showing for manual install

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

Android M not showing normal permission like Internet, WIFI in the permission list. Its just saying No special permission to display. Is that how Android M will display permission, it will never show permission prior to install. Can any one experienced this before.

attached screenshot,please check it. [image]

Please help me to finding this answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html):

> When the user installs or updates the app, the system grants the app all permissions listed in the manifest that fall under PROTECTION_NORMAL. For example, alarm clock and internet permissions fall under PROTECTION_NORMAL, so they are automatically granted at install time. For more information about how normal permissions are handled, see Normal Permissions.
>
> The system may also grant the app signature permissions, as described in System components and signature permissions. **The user is not prompted to grant any permissions at install time.**

(emphasis added)

Comment: Thank you very much quick response.